# Segmentation fault core dump [C language, linked list]

Tags: c, data-structures, printing, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I want to display my list, however, it seems to have something wrong in my `print()` function. Please help me! Thanks a lot.
Im trying to create a Student Management System with single linked list, and below is just 2 functions to input the data to the list and display it before insert or delete anything. 
As I know, segmentation fault happens as I want to access the memory I m not allowed to, but it is so general. I need some detailed explanation and some solution for this!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define ID_LENGTH 5
#define NAME_LENGTH 51

typedef struct Student_t {
  char id[ID_LENGTH];
  char name[NAME_LENGTH];
  int grade;
  struct Student_t *next; 
} Student;

Student* head;

void input(){
  int n,i;
  Student* temp = (Student*) malloc(sizeof(Student*));
  printf("Enter the number of students: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("Enter the information of student no.%d\n",i+1);
    printf(" -ID: "); scanf("%s",&temp->id);
    printf(" -Name: "); //getchar(); gets(temp->name); //
    scanf("%s",&temp->name);
    printf(" -Grade: "); scanf("%d",&temp->grade);
  }
}

void print(){
  Student* temp = (Student*) malloc(sizeof(Student*));
  temp = head;
  printf("\t\tThe Student List\n\n");
  printf("%-10s%-40s%-10s\n","ID","Name","Grade");
  while(temp->next != NULL){  
    printf("%-10s%-40s%-10d\n",temp->id,temp->name,temp->grade);
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}
int main(){
  // head = NULL; //empty list
  input();  
  print();
}
```

Comment: Just noticed your malloc code...Why use the sizeof a pointer?  use sizeof the struct (typedef)

Comment: Are you sure you got Segmentation fault not in `input()` function but `print()` function? Undefined behavior, bad luck...

Comment: `print()` function is also bad because it causes memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

while you are implementing link list always use pen and paper and write down every step properly before starting coding. Write every steps for creating the list, inserting a new node, deleting a node. Never forget to assign the `next` pointer to NULL while creating a new node. Most of the time problem is always with `next` as your list's last node's `next` is assign with junk value instead of NULL.

Now first correct below statement. Here you should provide the struct name not pointer:-

```
Student* temp = (Student*) malloc(sizeof(Student));
temp->next = NULL;//always do it
head = temp;// now head is pointing to the first node of the list
```

Your below `for` loop is totally wrong. You are not creating a list here. You are using the same node all the time.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
printf("Enter the information of student no.%d\n",i+1);
printf(" -ID: "); scanf("%s",&temp->id);
printf(" -Name: "); //getchar(); gets(temp->name); //
scanf("%s",&temp->name);
printf(" -Grade: "); scanf("%d",&temp->grade);
```

}

Correct it like below:-

```
int i = 0;
while(1){       
printf("Enter the information of student no.%d\n",i+1);
printf(" -ID: "); scanf("%s",&temp->id);
printf(" -Name: "); //getchar(); gets(temp->name); //
scanf("%s",&temp->name);
printf(" -Grade: "); scanf("%d",&temp->grade);
if( ++i < n ){// each time you have to create a new node
   temp->next = (Student*) malloc(sizeof(Student));
   temp = temp->next;
   temp->next = NULL;
}
else
   break;
}
```

Correct your `print` function like below:-

```
void print(){
  Student* temp = head;// here you no need to create a new node. Just create a node which will point to the head
  printf("\t\tThe Student List\n\n");
  while(temp != NULL){  
    printf("%-10s%-40s%-10d\n",temp->id,temp->name,temp->grade);
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}
```